# I need to define the expression for the function f(x).

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

The function f: R → R is differentiable and satisfies the conditions

- f(2) = 1
- f(x) + xf´(x) = 2 with all x ∈ R.

Define the expression for the function f.

Comment: Can you write down $(xf(x))'?

Comment: Hint: $f(x)+xf'(x)=\left( xf(x) \right) '$

Comment: Wait a second, can we use product rule when any one of $u(x)$ or $v(x)$ is not differentiable in R? If we use it, we are getting a function which is not differentiable at $x =0$, which is a paradox.

Comment: @rikusp2002 In general, no, you can't use the product rule where one of the factors is not differentiable. This isn't a problem in either Kavi or Martin's comments, since $f$ is assumed to be differentiable (so that the ODE even makes sense) and $x \mapsto x$ is clearly differentiable. But, you have a point about $x = 0$ being a problem. Indeed, without the initial condition, the constant function $f(x) = 2$ is the only solution, and hence there is no solution to the initial value problem.

Answer (score 1):

$$xf'+x=2 \implies \frac{d(xf)}{dx}=2~\text{(integration)}\implies xf =2x+C \implies f(x)=2+\frac{C}{x}$$ Next $f(2)=1 \implies C=-2.$
So $f(x)=2(1-1/x)$ but it is not continuous and differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: The question did claim it's valid for all R, but we're having a contradiction and I cannot find the reason.

Comment: Maybe they want $f:R^+\to R$,

Comment: @Z Ahmed So R+ excludes zero?

Comment: Zero is called non-negative integer rather than positive integer.